# How to make scripts run in Guake terminal instead of normal terminal?

Tags: command-line, scripts, guake

I have installed Guake terminal and I find it amazing. I have many scripts added as .desktop files in launcher.

Now I want these scripts to run in the Guake terminal instead of opening in the normal Gnome terminal. How can I achieve this?

The .desktop file is such:

```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Terminal=true
  Icon=/path/to/icon/icon.svg
  Name=app-name
  Exec=/path/to/file/mount-unmount.sh
  Name=app-name
```

Comment: Can you provide the contents of such a .desktop launcher?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just edit your `.desktop` file as below,

`Exec=guake -e /path/to/script.sh`

By default this starts hidden window and runs there. If you want to start it as visible window use,

`Exec=guake -t -e /path/to/script.sh`

---

For default terminal it is `gnome-terminal`

Comment: okay so i should add `/bin/usr/guake/path/to/script.sh`? as guake is located in /bin/usr/guake...i.e it is its command

Comment: also,there is a space after /bin/usr/guake? like this- `/bin/usr/guake /pathr/to/script.sh`?

Comment: which one should work? the one with space or without space? or that does not matter?

Comment: @virpara...umm its not working...it gets directed to guake but no execution takes place in guake...

Comment: okay that worked but that dint initiate guake by itself...i had to press the hotkey to bring it up n then saw the stuff running there...cant it be made to pop up asa the script starts running?

Comment: @Nirmik i've edited answer.